# Scroll PanoramaItem Header in 'wide' PanoramaItem

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm interested in creating my own 'Hub' `Panorama`. I've gotten the 'wide' `PanoramaItem` working, but I'm trying now to mimic the behavior seen in the Marketplace hub, where the PanoramaItem Header scrolls as you move across the hub.

I'm looking for a way for it to smoothly animate to the end of the hub. Has anyone tried this before, or have any suggestions?

I'd imagine it would be something like this:

```
//OnPanoramaViewChanged
//get X location of viewport
//animate title to X location
```

However it doesn't appear that the Panorama has a `ScrollViewer` attached property.

In case you're curious, here's how I made a wide panorama item.

```
<controls:PanoramaItem  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Header="movies" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="900">
                <controls:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate  >
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource PanoramaHeaderBrush}" Text="{Binding}">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                <!-- line list with image placeholder and text wrapping -->
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ListBox.Template>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                                <Grid Background="{StaticResource ControlTitlesInactivePivotBrush}" Width="173" Height="173" >
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Text="Movie Title (2010)" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}"/>
                                    <Rectangle Fill="White" Height="48" Width="48" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"> 
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Test;component/movie_icn.png" />
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>

                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="Movie Title:" Margin="12,0,12,0" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Text="The Title" Margin="12,-6,12,0"  Foreground="Gray"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight Panorama control doens't support the behaviour you're after or provide the ability to customize it in a way that will let you do it.

If you really want this then you'll need to build your own control from scratch. I would expect this to be more effort than is justified. Just avoid creating a very wide PanoramaItem instead.

Comment: Thanks. I wish there was an easier way, but our client scrapped the idea anyway, so will no longer keep me up at night wondering ;p